# Grabbing the <textarea> value in php (HTML form)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I've got a simple HTML form where I switched from normal/traditional text fields to the textarea ones.

Within my form i have...

```
<form name="wreckAppForm" action="application2.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <textarea name="favSpec" form="wreckAppForm" rows="4" cols="100"></textarea>
...
```

Then, in application2.php I try to grab the information using...

```
$app_favSpec = $_POST["favSpec"];
```

But there is never anything in the value.  I'm clearly missing something.

I've looked into several other "solutions" on SO and other sites.  I've also read the W3Schools info on TEXTAREA along with other documentation.

I'm using the value (if I can ever get it) in a long concatenated string to eventually be written to a file.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What type of content do you get in the `textarea`?  Is it that you might need to use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)?

Comment: As @Sidstar said down below, check the output of `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: I did, it returns NULL.  Also, i tried using htmlspecialchars but with the same results.  (the input a user would put in there is a short essay style answer to a personal question...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:

```
id="wreckAppForm"
```

to your form element. The `form` element needs to have "wreckAppForm" in the ID for the textelement's `form="wreckAppForm"` to be valid.

Check out [the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) for more info. I'd also stay away from W3Schools, too.

Comment: Now that's an outstanding catch!  But, it might be me but the usage of `form` attribute should really be when the element is outside of the `form` element/block.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger it's always tough to answer these first ;) i'm glad I won for once!

Comment: Joseph for the WIN!  That worked.  Thank you kindly my friend.

Answer (score 0):

My browser crashed just as soon as I was going to hit the ***"Post your Answer"*** button (*a late answer*), so after taking the time of typing all this out and testing, I'm submitting it anyway.

That's because of the `form="wreckAppForm"` in your textarea; remove it.

(Tested)

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $app_favSpec = $_POST["favSpec"];
    echo $app_favSpec;

}

?>

<form name="wreckAppForm" action="" method="post" >
    <textarea name="favSpec" rows="4" cols="100"></textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```